# MERN app works locally but not on heroku netlify

Tags: session, heroku, mern

Does anyone know why after I login on localhost it works perfectly fine, but when I deploy it on heroku netlify, it's having trouble logging in

Short YT vid: https://youtu.be/lpyJo6tmiRs

**Login**

```
    app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
    
    
        voterModel.find({email: email}, {"email":1}, async (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                if(result.length > 0) {
                    const user = await voterModel.findOne({email: email})
                    const pass = await user.comparePassword(password)
    
                    if (pass) {
                        req.session.voter = result
    
                        var oneWeek = 60 * 60 * 24; //1 weeks                    
                        req.session.voter.expires = new Date(Date.now() + oneWeek);
                        req.session.voter.maxAge = oneWeek; 
    
                        console.log(req.session.voter)
                        res.send(result)
                    } else {
                        console.log("NOT LOGGED IN")
                        res.send({ message: 'Invalid email or password!'})
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("NOT LOGGED IN")
                    res.send({ message: 'Invalid email or password!'})
                }       
            }
        })
    })
```

**code for reading the session data**
After I log in, it goes to the condition else, instead going to loggedIn: true after I logged in

```
    app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
        if (await req.session.voter) {
            res.send({loggedIn: true, user: await req.session.voter})
        } else {
            res.send({loggedIn: false})
        }
    })
```

**session**

```
    app.use(session({
        key: "userId",  
        secret: "keyboard cat",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    }))
```

Comment: What is "heroku netlify"? Aren't Heroku and Netlify completely different services?

Comment: @Chris yes sorry I mean, heroku on my backend and netlify for front end